# ¿Por qué posee un array indefinido?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente javascript que representa unt exto cada tanto tiempo, pero al momento de resetar la variable para que vuelva a empezar hay un elemento que dice undefined

```
var nombre = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var leng = nombre.length;
var valor = nombre.length;

var random;






function change() {
    if (leng <= valor) {

       if(leng !=0 & leng >= 0){
        leng--;
       } else{
        leng = valor;
       }


        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nombre[leng]
    } 

}
setInterval(change, 1000)
```

el elemento "name" es solo un parrafo del html
alguien sabe que podria ser?

Comment: esta condicion esta mal, if(leng !=0 & leng >= 0){ dices que sea diferente a 9 y que sea igual o mayor a 0

Comment: la remplace por esto,    if (leng >= 1) sucede lo mismo ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estas dejando que la variable `leng` tome el valor de la longitud del la lista y luego lo indexa y el no encuentra ese elemento porque la lista tiene 4 elementos pero los indices inician desde 0 entonces si haces `nombre[4]` sera `undefined`.

Este código parece funcionar:

```
var nombre = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var leng = nombre.length;
var valor = nombre.length;

var random;



function change() {
    if (leng <= valor) {

       if(leng > 0){
        leng--;
       } else{
        leng = valor;
       }
      /*Nótese que acá verifico que leng sea un valor valido para indexar la lista*/
      if (leng < nombre.length){
          document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nombre[leng];
      }
    } 

}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

Comment: gracias!, como olvidar algo tan basico dios  ;( los solucione asi var valor = (nombre.length - 1);